# Create output files for pattern of reoccurring lines

Tags: bash, unix

I have one flat file, which contains multiple sequence alignments per cluster. The concept of the file looks like this:

```
# Input file.fasta

>ID1
>ID1
BSMCMKMA
>ID2
OINAOINV
>ID3
MPOMMSG
>ID4
>ID4
MMVAMOPMOP
>ID5
MMIOPMMOPVOM
>ID6
>ID6
POOPAMPOFM
```

The pattern for a new cluster to start is that the ID of the representative sequence appears twice. So in the example are three clusters, the first contains ID1, ID2, ID3, the second contains ID4, ID5 and the third only contains ID6, as in the cluster is basically only one sequence.

How do I read in the file and create a file for each cluster with the threshold that the cluster should contain at least two ID-sequence-pairs, so that for example (ID1, ID2, ID3) and (ID4, ID5) with their sequences are written in one file each per bracket, but not (ID6), because it only contains one sequence.

```
# desired output

# file_ID1.fasta
>ID1
BSMCMKMA
>ID2
OINAOINV
>ID3
MPOMMSG

# file_ID4.fasta
>ID4
MMVAMOPMOP
>ID5
MMIOPMMOPVOM
```

I thought about using awk, but I cannot figure out how to write the pattern awk should look for! I am sure I could find a way with python, but I hope that there is a nicer and faster way with bash.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show us whatever efforts you've made, even if they are trivial and _not_ working

Comment: That is not a properly formatted fasta file. I'm pretty sure it is the result of a pre-processing of the original file. Maybe it would be easier if you get the group information in another file and use that with the original fasta to arrange the groups.

Comment: @Inian I tried around with awk/gawk and could figure out a way! I will post it straight away: `gawk '{ if($1 ~ ">") {if (prev==$1) {n++} ; prev=$1 ; next} else {print prev > "ID"n; print > "ID"n}}' input.fasta`
I basically set variables for the previous and next line (prev,next) and used a counter n++ for naming the new files.
@Poshi You are right, the file results from a clustered multiple sequence alignment database! 
I hope I clarified everything.

Comment: @MaximilianSenftleben Good job. You should `close()` the old file when you start writing to a new file to avoid running out of filedescriptors. Also, you should copy that comment to an answer to gain much deserved reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the following is the answer:

```
gawk '{ if($1 ~ ">") {if (prev==$1) {n++} ; prev=$1 ; next} else {print prev > "ID"n; print > "ID"n; close()}}' input.fasta
```